# How to skip case while using String replaceAll

Tags: java, string, uppercase

Example my string have :

```
text = " Hi {fullname}, wellcome u join my group"
```

this is my code:

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\{fullname\\}", user.getMobile() != null ? user.getMobile() : "");
```

but now i have problem if {fullname} is {FULLNAME} or {Fullname} or {fuLLname}, i cant find exactly what i want and replace it.
Anyone have a solution please help me! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use **(?i)** as a prefix of your token "fullname" which will make it case insensitive so it will work for any Upper and Lower case combination of your token "fullname" 
`"{FULLname} , {fullNAME} , {FulLName} ,{fuLLname}"`

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\{(?i)fullname\\}", user.getMobile() != null ? user.getMobile() : "");
```

Answer (score 2):

ReplaceAll takes regex, so you can try `(?i)` ignorecase in regex

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\{(?i)fullname\\}", us...
```

That works for all `{fullname} , {FULLNAME} , {Fullname} ,{fuLLname}`

Answer (score -1):

Try using this

```
    String ans="Hi {fullname}, wellcome u join my group";

    ans = ans.replaceAll("\\{[a-zA-Z]*\\}", "ANYTHING");

    System.out.println(ans);
```